# MapBox MapView Attribution Popup Errors

Tags: ios, ios7, mapbox

This is on iOS 7 and using the 1.2.0 MapBox SDK.
On maps that have the info icon in the lower right, when the attribution shows I get the following errors:

> Error: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
>   error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
>   context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
>   system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>
> Error: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is
>   a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an
>   invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation
>   of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
>
> Error: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious
>   error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid
>   context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of
>   system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please
>   fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

I also don't have whatever graphic is supposed to be in the View.  There is a empty space where I'm assuming the MapBox logo would be.

Answer (score 0):

The MapBox.bundle wasn't getting included in the build correctly.  I had to remove it and add it back in.  Then the graphics showed up properly and the errors were no longer generated.